# How can I get the key intersect of two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I have two arrays as shown blow

```
//array 1
Array
(
    [0] => 223
    [1] => 216
)

/array 2
Array
(
    [221] => Bakers
    [220] => Construction
    [223] => Information Technology
    [216] => Jewellery
    [217] => Photography
    [222] => Retailers
)
```

I want that text where key (values) of first array matches to second array (keys).

expected result:

```
Information Technology, Jewellery
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach( $array1 as $index ) {
  $result[] = $array2[ $index ];
}
echo implode( ', ', $result );
```

Answer (score 6):

Just get the [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) of the keys, but since you have the keys as values in the first array you have to flip it with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php), e.g.

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($array2, array_flip($array1)));
```

Comment: Nice one. Very clean and spot on.